# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Node # Node is a class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need help accessing class values.

This is my Node class.

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.parent = None
```

This is another class where I access the class above.

```
class RRT():
    def __init__(self, start, goal, obstacle_list):
        self.start = Node(start[0], start[1])  # start node for the RRT
        self.goal = Node(goal[0], goal[1])     # goal node for the RRT
        self.obstacle_list = obstacle_list     # list of obstacles 
        self.node_list = []    # list of nodes added while creating the RRT
    ...
```

I store start in another function within my RRT class like this `self.node_list = [self.start]`

```
    def getNearestNode(self, random_point):
        minDist = 1e5
        for ii in self.node_list:
            nodePt = [None, None]
            # error occurs at line below
            nodePt[0] = self.node_list[ii].x
            nodePt[1] = self.node_list[ii].y
            # this function takes 2 coordinate lists and computes the distance
            dist = self.calcDistNodeToPoint(nodePt, random_point)
            if dist < minDist:
                minDist = dist
                index = ii
        return index
```

I get this error message `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Node`

Comment: Please post the full stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python for loops are for-each loops. `ii` is the element itself, not an index.

You should do:

```
nodePt[0] = ii.x
nodePt[1] = ii.y
```

Or even better, don't define nodePt before and just do:

```
nodePt = ii.x, ii.y
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and tip. Looks like I can't shrug matlab off me